# How to set the elevation of an AppBarLayout programmatically in the Android Support Library v24.0.0?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design

When upgrading from the Android Support Library v23.4.0 to v24.0.0, setting the elevation to 0 programmatically to an AppBarLayout stopped working:

```
appBayLayout.setElevation(0);
```

It does work when setting the elevation in the XML.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Edit**

The `AppBarLayout` from v24.0.0 uses a `StateListAnimator` that defines the elevation depending on its state. So using `setElevation` will have no effect if a `StateListAnimator` is being used (which happens by default). Set the `elevation` via the XML or programmatically (both for API >= 21):

```
StateListAnimator stateListAnimator = new StateListAnimator();
stateListAnimator.addState(new int[0], ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "elevation", 0));
appBarLayout.setStateListAnimator(stateListAnimator);
```

**Old answer**

This seems to be an [issue of the design support library](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213895). The problem is related to the way the elevation is set programmatically, using `setElevation`. Setting it from the XML is placing a `StateListAnimator` in the view and not calling `setElevation`. However, `setElevation` should work.

Here there is a workaround:

```
setDefaultAppBarLayoutStateListAnimator(appBarLayout, 0);

@SuppressLint("PrivateResource")
private static void setDefaultAppBarLayoutStateListAnimator(final View view, final float targetElevation) {
    final StateListAnimator sla = new StateListAnimator();

    // Enabled, collapsible and collapsed == elevated
    sla.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.enabled, android.support.design.R.attr.state_collapsible,
            android.support.design.R.attr.state_collapsed},
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "elevation", targetElevation));

    // Enabled and collapsible, but not collapsed != elevated
    sla.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.enabled, android.support.design.R.attr.state_collapsible,
            -android.support.design.R.attr.state_collapsed},
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "elevation", 0f));

    // Enabled but not collapsible == elevated
    sla.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.enabled, -android.support.design.R.attr.state_collapsible},
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "elevation", targetElevation));

    // Default, none elevated state
    sla.addState(new int[0], ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "elevation", 0));

    view.setStateListAnimator(sla);
}
```

This is taken from what the constructor does, calling a method in the class `ViewUtilsLollipop` in v24.0.0.

Comment: Which `view` is used in your example `stateListAnimator.addState(new int[0], ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "elevation", 0));`?

Comment: @VolodymyrKhodonovych the one passed as a parameter

Comment: I have error in android 21 like this > JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void
> android.view.View.setElevation(float) on null object

Comment: @VolodymyrKhodonovych it seems that your view object reference is null

Answer (score 8):

One more possible solution for this is to add **`android:stateListAnimator="@null"`** to your `AppBarLayout` as shown below.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

Comment: I used both `appBarLayout.setElevation(0)` and `appBarLayout.setStateListAnimator(null)` to disable elevation and `appBarLayout.setElevation(10.5)` to enable. It worked in run time and after screen rotation

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to change elevation of `AppBarLayout` in runtime and `setElevation(..)` did the trick.

However after screen rotation and calling `setElevation(..)` from `onCreateOptionMenu` didn't work, but `setStateListAnimator(null)` did the trick.

Therefore I got this logic:

```
public final float appBarElevation = 10.5f;

public void disableAppBarElevation() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        appBarLayout.setElevation(0);
        appBarLayout.setStateListAnimator(null);
    }
}

public void enableAppBarElevation() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        appBarLayout.setElevation(appBarElevation);
    }
}
```