# setElevation() not working on AppBarLayout

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat

I have a `AppBarLayout`, in which I wish to programatically set the elevation to 0 in the `onCreate()` method. If I have an example `onCreate()` like this..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
    _appBar.setElevation(0);
}
```

The `AppBarLayout` elevation does NOT change.

However if I add a delay, for say, 400milliseconds, the `AppBarLayout` elevation DOES change.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
        Observable.just(_appBar)
        .delay(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<AppBarLayout>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(AppBarLayout appBarLayout) throws Exception {
                appBarLayout.setElevation(0);
            }
        });
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? and how I can fix this without a delay. I have also tried using `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);` as well, and using API 24

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved! instead of set elevation, I use:

```
StateListAnimator stateListAnimator = new StateListAnimator();
stateListAnimator.addState(new int[0], ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "elevation", 0));
appBarLayout.setStateListAnimator(stateListAnimator);
```

Please see the following answer for a more detailed explanation:

[How to set the elevation of an AppBarLayout programmatically in the Android Support Library v24.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992365/how-to-set-the-elevation-of-an-appbarlayout-programmatically-in-the-android-supp)